# Ultrasonic diffraction

Tags: diffraction, ultrasound

When ultrasonic is applied to a liquid it creates an acoustic grating in which some part have more refractive index and some part have low refractive index. When light is passed through this grating it only passes through the rarer part of the grating. Why it only passes through the rarer part only?